# android studio makes corrupted Colors.xml, then unknown errors occur

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Recently I was working with my android studio with no problems, suddenly my project started giving random errors(about my resources) after I tried to add a new library to my project.

I completely cleaned the library but nothing got fixed, at all
I wanted to make a new project, and faced new errors

```
colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Android studio made a corrupted file like this for colors.xml:

```
����   3      area I ConstantValue   length  
temperature  weight  
<init> ()V Code LineNumberTable LocalVariableTable this array 
InnerClasses ,Lcom/example/a
```

When I fixed this xml, another error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
```

I have tried:

- Invalidate Cache/Restart
- Deleting .gradle folder in my C:\Users
- Redownload the gradle
- Delete gradle folder of project
- Choosing diffrent names for layouts and packages
- Restart PC
- 5 Hours Googling (no result)

And ic_launcher_round.xml as asked:

```
����   3 �  � � � 0abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark 
I ConstantValue   1abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light  
(abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material  
abc_btn_colored_text_material  abc_color_highlight_material
```

Comment: share `ic_launcher_round.xml` code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You don't need to reinstall Android Studio: close it and delete the folder `.AndroidStudioX.Y` (X and Y depend on your Android studio version) in the user folder.**

The answer is old, but I have the same problem today with Android Studio 3.3.2. I give my answer with the hope it can help other developers. In a random way, Android studio cannot open some files. In the first instance, I thought that the files were corrupted. After opening the same file with an external editor I realized that is not true.

[image: Error in Android Studio]

In the above example, the `.iml` file cannot be read by Android Studio. I open the same file with Notepad++ and I luckily saw that file was good.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why my answer receives a downvote. It solves my problem, that is similar to the question.

Comment: Thanks, its worked and it also less time consuming then the other options like reinstalling android studio

Comment: Awesome... This solution works for me. Thank a lot..

Comment: Looks like this is a better answer although time has passed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug which reported by many developers and I've faced that once.

The only fix is to reinstall the Android Studio or downloading the new version of the IDE but, ***don't import the old config when you reinstall or updating it***.

To be clear, changing `File-Encoding` in settings to `UTF-8` or `System Default` doesn't work either.

Comment: Please remember to not to import the old Android Studio config when you do the reinstalling. You can also go to `C:\Users\<yourusername>/` and remove the `.AndroidStudio<version>` folder to prevent suggesting the old config or using it automatically.